# Android rating bar going out of bounds of dialog

Tags: android, android-layout

[the rating bar inside my dialog box is going out of bounds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEgbL.png)[image]

```
 final AlertDialog.Builder popDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(ExercisesActivity.this);
 final RatingBar rb = new RatingBar(ExercisesActivity.this);
 popDialog.setIcon(android.R.drawable.btn_star_big_on);
 rb.setMax(6);
 popDialog.setTitle("Set Difficulty");
 popDialog.setView(rb);
 // Button OK
 popDialog.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok,
       new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
              //do things
       }

 });
 popDialog.create();
 popDialog.show();
```

`setMax()` has no effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you will add `RatingBar` directly in the `AlertDialog` then it will cause a wired output as we are generating `Ratingbar` dynamically and not setting width.

You can achieve the same by setting `LayoutParams` to your `RatingBar` and add your `RatingBar` into `LinearLayout` and add that `LinearLayout` view to the `AlertDialog`.

Check below Sample:

```
final AlertDialog.Builder popDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
popDialog.setTitle("Set Difficulty");
popDialog.setIcon(android.R.drawable.btn_star_big_on);

LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(ExercisesActivity.this);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
);

final RatingBar rating = new RatingBar(ExercisesActivity.this);
rating.setLayoutParams(lParams);
rating.setNumStars(6);
linearLayout.addView(rating);

popDialog.setView(linearLayout);

// Button OK
popDialog.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok,
    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            //do things
        }
    });
popDialog.create();
popDialog.show();
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Specify the height and width first:

```
 LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    );

linearLayout.addView(rb);
```

Sets the number of stars to show apply setNumStars(x). In order for these to be shown properly, it is recommended the layout width of this widget be wrap content. 
Like:

```
rb.setNumStars(6);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set your width to yourself like this :

```
 rb.getLayoutParams().width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT; 
// you can also use WRAP_CONTENT but I think that for your dialog MATCH_PARENT is better
```

Comment: rb has no width parameter

Answer (score 0):

**setMax()** method defines the maximum number of starts t6hat can be selected by the user.

As per your query i hope you are looking for set the number of stars to be diplayed.

so in your code **Remove**

```
rb.setMax(6);
```

And **Replace** it with

```
rb.setNumStars(6);
```

Hope iv gave you an solution :)